# Why is xlCalculationManual speeding up a non-dependent workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I thought that turning off automatic recalculation only sped up Excel sheets that contain formulas. For example, using VBA code to write values to sheet A, while sheet B contains formulas which is using the the values in sheet A.

However, I have noticed that my code speeds up dramatically if I turn off automatic calculation even when I only write values with VBA. That is, writing values to sheet A and nothing is using those values.

Can someone give a more thorough explanation what is happening? If sources are available, please provide that as well.

The code below takes roughly one second with automatic recalculation, but barely 0.1 second with manual recalculation.

```
Dim i
Dim start
Dim time

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
start = Timer

For i = 2 To 100
    Sheet1.Range("A" & i) = i

    Select Case Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value

        Case 1 To 20
            Sheet1.Range("B" & i) = "A"

        Case 21 To 40
            Sheet1.Range("B" & i) = "B"

        Case 41 To 60
            Sheet1.Range("B" & i) = "C"

        Case 61 To 80
            Sheet1.Range("B" & i) = "D"

        Case 81 To 100
            Sheet1.Range("B" & i) = "E"

    End Select

Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

time = Timer - start
Debug.Print time
```

Comment: Whenever something changes on a Sheet, All the Formulas are recalculated. That's why with Automatic calculation it's taking time. So it's the Same logic with or Without VBA, because you are changing something on the Sheets in your code.

Comment: Agree. However, my workbook contains no formulas. But still the simple VBA code above is dramatically faster when I turn off recalculation.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation of [Excel Calculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation):

> When calculation is set to automatic, recalculation occurs after every
>   data input and after certain events such as the examples given in the
>   previous section.

It does not mean that all cells/UDFs are recalculated every input. It means Excel tries to build the dependency tree and the calculation chain. Only the cells affected will be actually re-calculated.

Things that can slow down Excel calculations:

- Volatile and Non-Volatile Functions
  `NOW()`, `TODAY()`, `RANDBETWEEN()`, `OFFSET()`, `INDIRECT()`, `INFO` (depending on its arguments), `CELL` (depending on its arguments), `SUMIF` (depending on its arguments)
  and User defined function (UDFs) unless marked as volatile.

  All functions above are re-calculated **EVERY** cells change you are making in your VBA code regardless of the sheet/workbook. 
  You can do a simple test: 
  Open 2 new workbooks and enter =RAND() formula in one of the cells. In the other workbook, change some cell value. The =RAND() function will be recalculated.
- Array Formulas ([MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7))
- Setting Entire Row/Column as Reference
  Example: `ActiveCell.EntireColumn`, `ActiveCell.EntireRow`

Comment: Ok, so in my specific situation it is the "build the dependency tree and the calculation chain" that takes time? Because as I wrote, my workbook contains no formulas. I am simply writing values to cells via VBA.

Comment: It's hard to say 100%, but according to the documentation - yes. How many cells do you have in total? I would cut them by half and see if there is any change.

Comment: I write to 100 cells. If I instead write to 50 cells (i.e. changing the loop to 50 iterations), running time is cut to half.